# Need some form of redundancy for Blink Cameras

Tags: wireless-networking, security, redundancy, cellular-internet

Please direct me to question if this has already been answered.I searched hard for a duplicate.

I have about 5 Blink network cameras. 3 indoor, 1 outdoor, 1 blink mini. I live in a very boring townhouse neighborhood where all isp fiber connections enter each home in the same exact spot with bright orange visible cable exposed to the elements and anyone else who wishes it harm. It would be trivial for a burglar to cut the cord from outside and voila, they no longer record video. Blink cameras all store on the cloud and there is no local SD card.

All five cameras connect to a base station. The base station connects to my wifi, the wifi connects to my ISP’s fiber router (converted to cat6 once inside my home).

I was wondering if there was a way I can have my router switch networks if the Quanum (century link) network goes down? Even to my phone’s cellular data would be a good start.

At least there’d be recording if an incident happened while I was at home with my phone. I really wish I could emulate their cloud setup so I could just store things locally too. Could I buy an extra cell with low data usage for a permanent solution?

Router is a Quantum Fiber C5500XK. The wifi is a Deco “mesh” network that has access points all over your house.Tp Link Deco AC1200. Can either of these devices handle the routing portion?

The answer doesn’t have to be network redundancy, like I said, if I can store the video locally, that would be good too. Or do all three for that matter. Or maybe there is an even better answer this question.

Comment: You have read https://support.blinkforhome.com/using-your-camera/blink-storage-options?from_search=127464448 ?

Comment: Also check for Sync Module 2: https://support.blinkforhome.com/en_US/using-your-sync-module/sync-module-2-local-storage-operation